# Can I edit the text fields in a Google Form so that they are rich-text editors?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Would it be possible to create an add-on for Google Forms that changes the text fields for paragraph responses so that users can style their inputs similar to a Google Doc? I am new to using Google Script, so I am not sure if these types of features are able to be altered by an add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Forms add-ons and Google Apps Script work on the edition mode a form, not on the view mode, by the other hand there isn't a question for rich text answers.